# Using RAISERROR isn't working in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have the following code below:

```
BEGIN TRY 

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
       -- DO SOMETHIING

    COMMIT TRAN

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   IF(@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

   RAISERROR(ERROR_MESSAGE(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERROR_STATE()) --ERROR: Incorrect syntax near 'ERROR_MESSAGE'.

END CATCH
```

However, the RAISERROR statement isn't working.  What is wrong in the raise error statement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RAISERROR follows the same rules as any other stored procedure call. Parameters passed in must be a constant or a variable. You cannot pass a function directly as a parameter. See [Executing Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189915.aspx) for documentation on this.

```
/* Demo Code - Functions accept functions as parameters
               while stored procedures do not              */

create function dbo.fnDayOfWeek 
    (@date datetime) 
    returns int
as
begin
    declare @x int
    set @x = DATEPART(day,@date)
    return (@x)
end
go

/* Both statements are successful */
select dbo.fnDayOfWeek('2010-08-06')
go
select dbo.fnDayOfWeek(GETDATE())
go

drop function dbo.fnDayOfWeek
go

create procedure DayOfWeek
    @date datetime
as
begin
    select DATEPART(day,@date)
end
go

/* First call succeeds, second fails */
exec DayOfWeek @date = '2010-08-06'
go
exec DayOfWeek @date = getdate()
go

drop procedure DayOfWeek
go
```

Comment: Oh! I thought RAISEERROR is a function and not stored procedure.

Comment: Functions are not subject to the same restrictions. I've appended some demo code to my answer to illustrate the difference.

Answer (score 16):

Error is occurring because you directly using function in `Raiserror`(notice single e) so to avoid this try the below code
Try this is working for me

```sql
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

    SELECT 
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
               @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
               @ErrorState -- State.
               );
END CATCH;
```

Comment: dont know but i have debug whole given code in that i found that if i put functions directly instead of the variable it gives syntax error

Comment: I know its written here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177497.aspx#CodeSpippet2. But shouldn't `RAISERROR(ERROR_MESSAGE(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERROR_STATE())` directly work?

Comment: @TheKing Don't you mean Raise Rror?

Comment: @ErikE I didn't get your point... I was just saying why can't they put the statement like RAISERROR (ERROR_MESSAGE(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERROR_STATE() );

Comment: @theking never mind. It's already ruined if I have to explain it.