# Cannot use function calls as parameters to RAISERROR()

Tags: t-sql, error-handling

I am using a try-catch block in T-SQL, and I want to only catch a specific error number. In other cases, I am using RAISERROR() as a poor-man's re-throw to return error information to the application.

When I try the following, I get an "Incorrect syntax near 'error_message'" error:

```
raiserror
    (
         error_message()
        ,1
        ,1
    )
```

The following, however, works fine:

```
declare @err varchar(100)
set @err = error_message()

raiserror
    (
         @err
        ,1
        ,1
    )
```

I thought it might be a typecasting quirk, so I tried this, but that also yielded a syntax error:

```
raiserror
    (
         cast(error_message() as varchar(100))
        ,1
        ,1
    )
```

What's going on here? Why do I have to store the result of ERROR_MESSAGE() in a variable before using it as a parameter to RAISERROR(), instead of calling the function directly?

Comment: It merely a parsing issue. If you expect SQL to be a "real" programming language, you're in for a world of grief.

Comment: I second what Stu says. A more direct answer might be "SQL is a very very very old language and thus is, basically, rubbish". I have requested this behaviour be changed: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/352110/t-sql-use-scalar-functions-as-stored-procedure-parameters#details but have next to no hope that it'll actually happen.

Comment: Agreed re not a real language. At a MS SQL event 10 years ago, they bragged how, with 2008 T-SQL was now a "first class programming language" . The laughability of that claim was evident to everyone attending, but one can excuse a person thinking it should be one, since that's the propaganda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below post answers your Question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3415125/639960

In a nutshell (quoted from above post):

> RAISERROR follows the same rules as any other stored procedure call.
>   Parameters passed in must be a constant or a variable. You cannot pass
>   a function directly as a parameter.

See [Executing Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189915.aspx) for documentation on this.

Comment: Or go right the RAISERROR doc http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx which states it must be a number, string, or string data type (not a statement or expression).

Comment: error_message() returns a string though; I don't see why it can't be evaluated and passed in

Comment: And I don't see why Microsoft can't buy a vowel, but they insist on RaIsError in an attempt to blame the Egyptian sun god for all our problems.  I encourage you to visit https://connect.microsoft.com/ to suggest an enhancement, but don't get your hopes up.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching error type by uncommenting set @Fail= GETDATE() and see its not very realiable

```
set nocount on
begin 

declare @ErrorMessage varchar(100)
declare @ErrorState varchar(100)
declare @ErrorSeverity varchar(100)
declare @ErrorNumber varchar(100)

declare @Fail int 

    begin try
        --set @Fail= GETDATE()
        set @Fail = 1/0
    end try

    begin catch

    print 'Why can''t it catch all type of errors like implicit conversion'
    SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage -- Message text.
               ,@ErrorState -- State.
               ,@ErrorSeverity -- Severity.
               );
    end catch
end
```